# Microsoft Band - Response status: not tile owner

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I'm trying to subscribe to tile events in the background using SubscribeToBackgroundTileEventsAsync. The problem is it usually doesn't work (sometimes it does). I added the observer to my app manifest.

The error I get is "Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Band.BandException'" with message "Response status not tile owner".

I use the same Guid for pinning the tile and subscribing to background events, so I don't see what's wrong.

My code:

```
if (await client.TileManager.AddTileAsync(myTile))
{
     await client.SubscribeToBackgroundTileEventsAsync(myTile.TileId);
     Debug.WriteLine("ok");
}
```

And the manifest

```
<Extensions>
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" EntryPoint="BandBackground.MyTileEventHandler">
    <uap:AppService Name="com.microsoft.band.observer" />
  </uap:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "not tile owner" error indicates that there is an app with a different PackageFamilyName that is currently subscribed to events from myTile.TileId. Most likely that other app is a previous installation of your app, and your app is using a constant for myTile.TileId.

If so, try generating a random Guid (instead of a constant) for your app's TileId prior to installing and subscribing. Or you could unsubscribe from background tile events prior to uninstalling/replacing your app.